# .Create(url) method of WebRequest class does not work

Tags: c#, http, methods, https, request

#### Problem

When I use the `.Create(url)` method of the `WebRequest` class, **it does not work**.

The `.Create(url)` method was not recognized by the IDE and marked as red because the method does not exist.
What do I have to do now to fix the problem.

[A GIF of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1ShB.gif)

#### Source Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace WebRequest
{
    class HttpMethods
    {


        public static string Get(string url, string referer, ref CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "GET";
            req.CookieContainer = cookies;
            req.UserAgent = "";
            req.Referer = referer;

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            cookies.Add(resp.Cookies);

            string pageSrc;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                pageSrc = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return pageSrc;
        }

        public static bool Post(string url, string postData, string referer, CookieContainer cookies)
        {
            string key = "Invalid credentials or user not activated!";

            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Method = "POST";
            req.CookieContainer = cookies;
            req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36";
            req.Referer = referer;
            req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8";

            Stream postStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
            postStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
            postStream.Dispose();

            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            cookies.Add(resp.Cookies);

            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
            string pageSrc = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Dispose();
            Console.WriteLine(pageSrc);
            return (!pageSrc.Contains(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It will be much easier to help if you try to build the project and add the compiler error to the question.

Comment: Try fully-qualifying the WebRequest and see if it is due to your namespace somehow confusing things...it's the same name as the class...just a thought

Comment: Sure, give me a moment. :)

Comment: You could be right!

Comment: HttpMethods.cs(38, 61): [CS0234] The type or namespace name 'Create' does not exist in the namespace 'WebRequest' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes you're right! The namespace was the problem! Thank you! :)